# Cant combine sheets using readxl and purr

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, bind, readxl

I have the same problem that in the question [Can't Combine X <character> and X <double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187461/cant-combine-x-character-and-x-double)
but instead with several .csv files with a .xlsx file with 32 sheets. All the sheets have identical columns name and the same number of columns.

I have tried all the approaches proposed in the latter question and in anothers from Stack Overflow with no success.

My script looks like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(readxl)

setwd("C:mypath/LANCES/EXCEL")

read_excel("Lances_9021.xlsx")

path <- "Lances_9021.xlsx"
path %>% excel_sheets() 

bd <- path %>%
  excel_sheets() %>%
  purrr::set_names() %>%
  purrr::map_df(read_excel,
         path = path)
```

And I get the following error from rlang::last_error()

> <error/vctrs_error_incompatible_type>
> Can't combine `..1$VALIDEZ`  and `..32$VALIDEZ` .
> Backtrace:

1. `%>%`(...)
2. purrr::map_df(., read_excel, path = path)
3. dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = .id)
4. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
5. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
6. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
7. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
8. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)

> 

I have tried using dply::mutate and mutate_if but it did not work.

Any hint will be more than welcome.

Thanks

Ps: I started a new question instead of asking in the question because I was not sure it was correct to ask in a previous question.

Comment: You have to have the same column's types in all sheets in the excel. Otherwise you can redefine it with `col_types = ` in `read_excel()`

Comment: I deal with issues like this all the team--you need to recreate the problem for us and post the data so we can reproduce the error

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko, thanks for the advice. Using `col_types="text"` I skipped the problem but now all colums are "character" and I have to convert variables name by name

Comment: @JuanCarlos, but you are aware, that you can supply `col_types` for all columns at once? Like `read_excel("yo.xlsx", col_types = c("date", "skip", "guess", "numeric"))`. See https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html

Comment: @BenG, here it is a sample of the .xlsx file [link] https://mega.nz/file/NJhGFTJQ#kpu-dI7CY7Hex0gt3OsZuPhESTpQNTIGRLMRnD48qg8

I have left the first 10 rows of each year to make the file more manageable. Thanks for your help because I am sure that there is a more elegant way of solving the problem that passing all the columns (38) to character and then getting back to its initial format one by one.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko, yes I am aware of it. The problem is that I have 38 columns and this gets a bit hard to keep track of which column is being imported as which type